# Can compiled views be referenced by a separate application in .NET 6?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm currently trying to migrate legacy ASP.Net Web Forms to .NET Core. I intially started with .NET Core 3.1, but, after publishing to production, found the specific "feature" that IIS will lock the .dlls, preventing from publishing again since they are locked. There are work arounds, but I want the functionality that was already in .NET Framework...

In .NET Framework and .NET Core 3.1, you can reference precompiled views from a DLL - works great. We have our `_Layout.cshtml`, a `_Navigation.cshtml`, and a few other views that are precompiled so they can be used and referenced in each project for a consistent look and feel between all applications.

In .NET 6, there is no more `[MyAssembly].Views.dll` and instead, the views are compiled to the `[MyAssembly].dll`. Furthermore, they've made the views `internal sealed`, so yunno, nifty...

The issue I have is that my other projects cannot reference the precompiled view now. I've tried just about every "path" possible for the referencing assembly to find the views, but I always get the error "The layout view '~/Views/Share/_Layout.cshtml' could not be located. The following locations were searched:" when trying it out.

Is there ANYWAY to reference views that are precompiled in a different .dll?

Answer (score 1):

After lots of banging my head against the wall - I found an acceptable solution:

In the `.csproj` file of the project that contains the view that you want to reference add a new ItemGroup:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Web\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

In the project that will reference the view:

1. Add "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" via NuGet
2. Add the following to the Startup.cs (or Program.cs if you switch to the .NET 6 way of startup):

```
services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(
        typeof(SomeClassInTheReferencedAssembly).Assembly
    ));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Very important point to note, the views supplied in a DLL as embedded resources appear to be case sensitive, so your view names must match the filename case.

e.g. `return View("index")` won't work if the view is called `Index.cshtml`, you would need to use `return View("Index")` instead.

Update: You also need to replicate your `_ViewStart.cshtml` file in your library Views folder, else your asp tags may not build.

I followed some other SO answers and found they, and the referenced Microsoft pages, were missing key details to make it work (marking views as embedded resources and views appear to become case sensitive):

### Research steps:

1. Cloned the Microsoft [Sample app](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/mvc/advanced/app-parts/sample2) mentioned on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
2. Ran WebAppParts sample (.Net core 3.0) - Worked
3. Updated WebAppParts sample to .Net 6.0 - Worked
4. Created a brand new .Net 6 Web Application
5. Added MySharedApp .Net 6 library
6. Added Snippet to the program main setup and called this instead of `AddControllersWithViews`

   ```
   public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       var assembly = typeof(MySharedController).Assembly;
       services.AddControllersWithViews()
           .AddApplicationPart(assembly)
           .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

       services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
       { options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(assembly)); });
   }
   ```
7. Added menu hyperlink to `MyShared/index` in _Layout.cshtml - It cannot find the view
8. Diff'ed the sample project against my new one and slowly migrated settings/changes across.
9. Added `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded` NuGet to library.
10. Found that any shared views needed to be marked as `Embedded resource` in the views `Build Action`. This was not apparent in the sample app as the view displays as `Content` in the sample app, despite this entry in the .csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\MyShared\Index.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

11. After all these changes, my .Net 6.0 test web app started sharing the library's views and controller.
12. Final example below is what I reduced my app code to in `Program.Main()`. Feel free to remove the Auth or Json lines if not needed:

    ```
       var assembly = typeof(AnySharedController).Assembly;

       builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
           .AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)
           .AddApplicationPart(assembly)
           .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
           .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

       builder.Services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
       {
           options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(assembly));
       });
    ```
13. While migrating Views to a library, I found that partial views were not found unless the view or partial view name was the same case.

e.g. This one failed

```
@(await Html.PartialAsync("titlepartial"))
```

Then this one worked

```
@(await Html.PartialAsync("TitlePartial"))
```